# C# - How to change a backColor in generated PictureBox from another class?

Tags: c#, colors, picturebox

**I generate the pictureBoxes like this.**

```
        public PictureBox[,] newButton;

        int space = 2;
        int size = 15;
        int xAreaSize = 40;
        int yAreaSize = 32;

        Spot spot = new Spot();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            newButton = new PictureBox[xAreaSize, yAreaSize];
            GenerateArea();
        }

        private void GenerateArea()
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < yAreaSize; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < xAreaSize; x++)
                {
                    newButton[x, y] = new PictureBox();
                    newButton[x, y].Width = size;
                    newButton[x, y].Height = size;
                    newButton[x, y].Name = "pb" + x + "-" + y;
                    newButton[x, y].Tag = x + "-" + y;
                    newButton[x, y].Text = x + "-" + y;
                    newButton[x, y].Top = (y * (size + space)) + space;
                    newButton[x, y].Left = (x * (size + space)) + space;
                    newButton[x, y].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                    newButton[x, y].MouseClick += SpotClick;
                    newButton[x, y].BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
                    newButton[x, y].Parent = this;
                }
            }
        }
```

**And trying to change color from another class in another file like this.**
And there is no error or issue but color is the same.

```
form1.newButton[node.X, node.Y + 1].BackColor = spot.BLUE;
```

Comment: 99.99% probability that created an instance of Form1, and it is called `form1`?  If so, that instance of Form1 is NOT the same one that you see on your screen.  It's an invisible instance that has never been shown; thus "no effect" when you change colors.  To fix this, you need a reference to the actual Form1 that is on your screen.  Either, (1) Pass a reference in when you create your helper class, or (2) Iterate the [Application.OpenForms](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.openforms?view=netcore-3.1) collection to find the open instance of Form1.

Comment: Thanks, it works.

Comment: You're welcome!...from 5 months ago though?